# Uri.encode() encodes wrong

Tags: android, kotlin, encode

So, I need to encode my url. 
For that I use `Uri.encode()`:

```
private const val CHARS= "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%"

if (query != null) {
     query = Uri.encode(query, Chars)
}
```

But, it encodes weirdly... `[` is `%255B`, when it should be  and `]` is `%255D`, when it should be `%5D`

Update: Turns out `Uri.encode()` works just fine. The problem is how I build the url. I do it by using `HttpUrl` and after I encode `query` I do `HttpUrl.build()` which encodes the url second time?

Comment: What is the value of `Chars`? Your code shows `CHARS` and it contains neither `[` nor `]`.

Comment: Sorry. `Chars` are the ones that shouldn't be `encoded`.

Answer (score 1):

You seems to be calling android.net.Uri's:

```
public static String encode (String s, String allow)
```

From the documentation, this:

> Encodes characters in the given string as '%'-escaped octets using the
>   UTF-8 scheme. Leaves letters ("A-Z", "a-z"), numbers ("0-9"), and
>   unreserved characters ("_-!.~'()*") intact. Encodes all other
>   characters with the exception of those specified in the allow
>   argument.

So you need pass the URL string  as the s parameter. And it will return an encoded version of the url suitable for use as a URI component.

Answer (score 0):

URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");

The URL encoding is can be [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) which encodes with %. Provide "UTF-8" in chars it will work. Hope this will work for you.